# How to convert a string to an integer in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, integer, data-conversion

How do I convert a string to an integer in JavaScript?

Comment: This page has a great table at the bottom that compares various methods of doing the conversion: https://medium.com/@nikjohn/cast-to-number-in-javascript-using-the-unary-operator-f4ca67c792ce

Comment: In absence of OP's clarification, this question could be interpreted in the sense of converting *any* string to a number, i.e. turning "dog" into a number (which of course can be done).

Comment: Taking the bait:  @DanielCarrera .. and yet no one here interpreted the question that way. Probably because if that was the goal, it would very likely have been worded quite differently. After all, the process of doing so ("hashing") is not, nor has ever been, AFAIK, referred to as "**converting** to an integer".

Comment: For **non-standard *locale*** (Ex. `123456789.123` is `123 456 789,12`in `fr-FR`) [see this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25645163/104380)

Comment: To parse numbers with different numeral systems (for example, Persian/Farsi or Arabic), see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70474143/8583692) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25645163/8583692).

Answer (score 2912, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use the native `Number` function:

```
var x = Number("1000")
```

If that doesn't work for you, then there are the **parseInt**, **unary plus**, **parseFloat with floor**, and **Math.round** methods.

#### parseInt()

```
var x = parseInt("1000", 10); // You want to use radix 10
    // So you get a decimal number even with a leading 0 and an old browser ([IE8, Firefox 20, Chrome 22 and older][1])
```

#### Unary plus

If your string is already in the form of an integer:

```
var x = +"1000";
```

#### floor()

If your string is or might be a float and you want an integer:

```
var x = Math.floor("1000.01"); // floor() automatically converts string to number
```

Or, if you're going to be using Math.floor several times:

```
var floor = Math.floor;
var x = floor("1000.01");
```

#### parseFloat()

If you're the type who forgets to put the radix in when you call parseInt, you can use parseFloat and round it however you like. Here I use floor.

```
var floor = Math.floor;
var x = floor(parseFloat("1000.01"));
```

#### round()

Interestingly, Math.round (like Math.floor) will do a string to number conversion, so if you want the number rounded (or if you have an integer in the string), this is a great way, maybe my favorite:

```
var round = Math.round;
var x = round("1000"); // Equivalent to round("1000", 0)
```

Comment: For the last case, if you just want to truncate the number (round toward zero) you can still use parseInt. It will parse the number up to the period.

Comment: Yes. Any time I'm using "floor" much I do var floor=Math.floor which tightens things up a bit. I just wanted to show what happens with unary plus when you have a float. People run into trouble all the time because 1) People end up with strings when they want numbers. 2) JavaScript uses "+" for both addition and string concatenation.

Comment: http://jsperf.com/performance-of-parseint/29 , hy @jedierikb i was edit jsperf link. Adding `'4'>>0` and `'4'>>>0`.

Comment: Update to 2015: as of ECMAScript 5, strings with a leading zero "0" also get default radix 10, instead of 8. Explicitly specifying radix 10 is only necessary for older browsers.
https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#parseInt()_ignores_leading_zeros

Comment: Note that Number('') succeeds (returning 0), even though most people wouldn't consider the empty string to represent a valid number.  And parseInt('3q') succeeds (returning 3) even though most people wouldn't consider '3q' to be a valid number.

Comment: Heads up. Both `parseInt` and `parseFloat` happily accepts letters. Only `Number` returns `NaN` consistently.

Comment: In my opinion, parsing an integer should result with exception/`NaN` for every value which is not exactly an integer. Therefore none of these work as `Number('2.2')` coerces to `2` and `Number('')` coerce to 0.

Comment: parseInt("6-4") returns 6, whereas Number("6-4") returns NaN.... this could be a significant different if you're testing strings that might be guids, for example.

Comment: `Number(null)` return `0` too

Comment: Before conversion, you may need to use a regular expression to check what type of number the string is. **Positive Integer (no leading zeros)**: `str.match(/^[1-9][0-9]*$/)`. **Whole Number (zero or positive integer with no leading zeros)**: `str.match(/^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$/)`. **Integer (no leading zeros)**: `str.match(/^(0|-?[1-9][0-9]*)$/)`. **Decimal (no leading zeros)**: `str.match(/^(0|-?[1-9][0-9]*)\.[0-9]*$/)`. **Any Number (no leading zeros)**: `str.match(/^(0|-?[1-9][0-9]*)(\.[0-9]*)?$/)`. The expressions can be altered for other cases.

Comment: [Unary plus is preferred](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus#description) according to MDN.

Comment: ，`good but not enough .`


``` 
Hereis 11 ways to convert a string to a number using JavaScript.

`using the Number() function`
`using the parseInt() function`
`using the parseFloat() function`
`using the unary plus operator (+)`
`multiplying the string by the number 1`
`dividing the string by the number 1`
`subtracting the number 0 from the string`
`using the bitwise NOT operator (~)`
using the Math.floor() function
using the Math.ceil() function
using the Math.round() function

from https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-number-in-javascript/
```

Answer (score 291):

Try parseInt function:

```
var number = parseInt("10");
```

But there is a problem. If you try to convert "010" using parseInt function, it detects as octal number, and will return number 8. So, you need to specify a radix (from 2 to 36). In this case base 10.

```
parseInt(string, radix)
```

Example:

```
var result = parseInt("010", 10) == 10; // Returns true

var result = parseInt("010") == 10; // Returns false
```

Note that `parseInt` ignores bad data after parsing anything valid.
This guid will parse as 51:

```
var result = parseInt('51e3daf6-b521-446a-9f5b-a1bb4d8bac36', 10) == 51; // Returns true
```

Comment: Radix is no longer required in 2016.

Comment: It might not be for newer browsers but radix is still required for backwards compatibility.

Comment: Note that this ignores bad data after the number. For example, `parseInt('0asdf', 10)` produces `0`.

Comment: LATEST: parseInt("010") == 10; // Returns true now - press ctrl-shift-j and paste that into your browser console to see for yourself :)

Comment: let x = '5';

let y = +x;

console.log(y);

Output = 5

Answer (score 159):

There are two main ways to convert a string to a number in JavaScript.  One way is to parse it and the other way is to change its type to a Number.  All of the tricks in the other answers (e.g., unary plus) involve implicitly coercing the type of the string to a number.  You can also do the same thing explicitly with the Number function.

**Parsing**

```
const parsed = parseInt("97", 10);
```

parseInt and parseFloat are the two functions used for parsing strings to numbers.  Parsing will stop silently if it hits a character it doesn't recognize, which can be useful for parsing strings like "92px", but it's also somewhat dangerous since it won't give you any kind of error on bad input, instead you'll get back NaN unless the string starts with a number. The whitespace at the beginning of the string is ignored.  Here's an example of it doing something different from what you want, and giving no indication that anything went wrong:

```
const widgetsSold = parseInt("97,800", 10); // widgetsSold is now 97
```

It's good practice to always specify the radix as the second argument.  In older browsers, if the string started with a 0, it would be interpreted as octal if the radix wasn't specified which took a lot of people by surprise.  The behavior for hexadecimal is triggered by having the string start with 0x if no radix is specified, e.g., `0xff`. The standard actually changed with [ECMAScript 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#5th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2009), so modern browsers no longer trigger octal when there's a leading 0 if no radix has been specified.  parseInt understands radixes up to base 36, in which case both upper and lower case letters are treated as equivalent.

**Changing the Type of a String to a Number**

All of the other tricks mentioned above that don't use parseInt, involve implicitly coercing the string into a number.  I prefer to do this explicitly,

```
var cast = Number("97");
```

This has different behavior to the parse methods (although it still ignores whitespace).  It's more strict: if it doesn't understand the whole of the string than it returns `NaN`, so you can't use it for strings like `97px`.  Since you want a primitive number rather than a Number wrapper object, make sure you don't put `new` in front of the Number function.

Obviously, converting to a Number gives you a value that might be a float rather than an integer, so if you want an integer, you need to modify it.  There are a few ways of doing this:

```
var rounded = Math.floor(Number("97.654"));  // other options are Math.ceil, Math.round
var fixed = Number("97.654").toFixed(0); // rounded rather than truncated
var bitwised = Number("97.654")|0;  // do not use for large numbers
```

Any bitwise operator (here I've done a bitwise or, but you could also do double negation as in an earlier answer or a bit shift) will convert the value to a 32 bit integer, and most of them will convert to a signed integer.  Note that this **will not do want you want for large integers**.  If the integer cannot be represented in 32 bits, it will wrap.

```
~~"3000000000.654" === -1294967296
// This is the same as
Number("3000000000.654")|0
"3000000000.654" >>> 0 === 3000000000 // unsigned right shift gives you an extra bit
"300000000000.654" >>> 0 === 3647256576 // but still fails with larger numbers
```

To work correctly with larger numbers, you should use the rounding methods

```
Math.floor("3000000000.654") === 3000000000
// This is the same as
Math.floor(Number("3000000000.654"))
```

Bear in mind that coercion understands exponential notation and Infinity, so `2e2` is `200` rather than NaN, while the parse methods don't.

**Custom**

It's unlikely that either of these methods do exactly what you want.  For example, usually I would want an error thrown if parsing fails, and I don't need support for Infinity, exponentials or leading whitespace.  Depending on your use case, sometimes it makes sense to write a custom conversion function.

Always check that the output of Number or one of the parse methods is the sort of number you expect.  You will almost certainly want to use `isNaN` to make sure the number is not NaN (usually the only way you find out that the parse failed).

Comment: It depends whether you want your code to also accept `97,8,00` and similar or not.  A simple trick is to do a `.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "")` which will remove all non digits from your string and then do the conversion afterwards.  This of course will ignore all kinds of crazy strings that you should probably error on rather than just parse...

Comment: @kybernetikos should probably be `.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "")`, otherwise "1.05" will become "105".

Comment: Quite right, although I wouldn't use something like that for important code anyway - there are so many ways it can let something through you really don't want to let through.

Comment: I found using Number much more readable in code so thank you for pointing it out as a solution.

Comment: @kybernetikos In `var fixed = Number("97.654").toFixed(0); // rounded rather than truncated`, we are getting a `string` (because of the `.toFixed` method) instead of a  `number` (integer). If we want the rounded integer it's probably better to just use `Math.round("97.654");`

Comment: @EduZamora good point.  toFixed seems that it's best used for formatting rather than anything else.

Comment: @kybernetikos and J.Steve, in this whole long thread, yours is the only answer that address comma separators (e.g., "10,000" is = "10000").  This is quite a common occurrence, you should add this as an answer to the question (get credit for it)!

Answer (score 63):

## Fastest

```
var x = "1000"*1;
```

### Test

Here is little comparison of speed (macOS only)... :)

For Chrome, 'plus' and 'mul' are fastest (>700,000,00 op/sec), 'Math.floor' is slowest. For Firefox, 'plus' is slowest (!) 'mul' is fastest (>900,000,000 op/sec). In Safari 'parseInt' is fastest, 'number' is slowest (but results are quite similar, >13,000,000  <31,000,000). So Safari for cast string to int is more than 10x slower than other browsers. So the winner is '**mul**' :)

You can run it on your browser by this link
https://jsperf.com/js-cast-str-to-number/1

[image]

I also tested `var x = ~~"1000";`. On Chrome and Safari, it is a little bit slower than `var x = "1000"*1` (<1%), and on Firefox it is a little bit faster (<1%).

Comment: There's no significant difference between the results of tests A, B, E and F - they're all essentially the same,

Comment: I got `~~"1000"` faster on Chrome, but they are all so close

Answer (score 59):

**ParseInt()** and **+** are different.

```
parseInt("10.3456") // returns 10

+"10.3456" // returns 10.3456
```

Comment: presumably `+"..."` is essentially `Number("...")`.

Comment: Always specify the base: `parseInt("10.3456", 10)` if you don't want to have a surprise one of these days, cf https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt `Be careful — this does not always default to 10!`

Answer (score 40):

I use this way of converting string to number:

```
var str = "25";       // String
var number = str*1;   // Number
```

So, when multiplying by 1, the value does not change, but JavaScript automatically returns a number.

But as it is shown below, this should be used if you are sure that the `str` is a number (or can be represented as a number), otherwise it will return [NaN](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/NaN#Noun) - not a number.

You can create simple function to use, e.g.,

```
function toNumber(str) {
    return str*1;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22440945/edit) (it covers answers and program output as well). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 38):

Try parseInt.

```
var number = parseInt("10", 10); //number will have value of 10.
```

Comment: The proper answer to the question

Answer (score 30):

I love this trick:

```
~~"2.123"; //2
~~"5"; //5
```

The double bitwise negative drops off anything after the decimal point AND converts it to a number format. I've been told it's slightly faster than calling functions and whatnot, but I'm not entirely convinced.

Another method I just saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081987/what-good-does-zero-fill-bit-shifting-by-0-do-a-0/3082073#3082073) (a question about the JavaScript >>> operator, which is a zero-fill right shift) which shows that shifting a number by 0 with this operator converts the number to a **uint32** which is nice if you also want it **unsigned**.  Again, this converts to an **unsigned integer**, which can lead to strange behaviors if you use a signed number.

```
"-2.123" >>> 0; // 4294967294
"2.123" >>> 0; // 2
"-5" >>> 0; // 4294967291
"5" >>> 0; // 5
```

Comment: This **only works for 32bit numbers**. Bitwise operations will forcefully truncate larger values, so `parseInt("4294967296")` and `~~"4294967296"` end up with different results. Namely, `parseInt` will return `4294967296` while `~~` will return `0`.

Answer (score 23):

Please see the below example. It will help answer your question.

```
Example                  Result

parseInt("4")            4
parseInt("5aaa")         5
parseInt("4.33333")      4
parseInt("aaa");         NaN (means "Not a Number")
```

By using parseint function, it will only give op of integer present and not the string.

Comment: Always specify the base: `parseInt("20", 10)` if you don't want to have a surprise one of these days, cf https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt `Be careful — this does not always default to 10!`

Answer (score 20):

In JavaScript, you can do the following:

ParseInt

```
parseInt("10.5") // Returns 10
```

Multiplying with 1

```
var s = "10";
s = s*1;  // Returns 10
```

Using the unary operator (+)

```
var s = "10";
s = +s;  // Returns 10
```

Using a bitwise operator

(Note: It starts to break after `2140000000`. Example: `~~"2150000000" = -2144967296`)

```
var s = "10.5";
s = ~~s; // Returns 10
```

Using Math.floor() or Math.ceil()

```
var s = "10";
s = Math.floor(s) || Math.ceil(s); // Returns 10
```

Comment: This is more or less a repeat of [Nosredna's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133770/how-to-convert-a-string-to-an-integer-in-javascript/1133814#1133814) from 2009.

Comment: @PeterMortensen It didn't have bitwise operator and multiplying with 1

Answer (score 19):

Beware if you use parseInt to convert a float in scientific notation!
For example:

```
parseInt("5.6e-14")
```

will result in

```
5
```

instead of

```
0
```

Comment: Using `parseInt` wouldn't work right for a float. `parseFloat` works properly in this case.

Comment: This is a valid concern - even parseInt("2e2") which is an integer, would be 200 if parseInt understood exponential notation, but actually returns 2, because it doesn't.

Comment: @kybernetikos - IMHO it is not reasonable to expect parseInt to comprehend a float representation. More appropriate to parseFloat or Number, then round or truncate to int as desired. That is a clearer statement of intent.

Answer (score 13):

To convert a String into Integer, I recommend using parseFloat and ***not*** parseInt. Here's why:

**Using parseFloat:**

```
parseFloat('2.34cms')  //Output: 2.34
parseFloat('12.5')     //Output: 12.5
parseFloat('012.3')    //Output: 12.3
```

**Using parseInt:**

```
parseInt('2.34cms')  //Output: 2
parseInt('12.5')     //Output: 12
parseInt('012.3')    //Output: 12
```

So if you have noticed parseInt discards the values after the decimals, whereas parseFloat lets you work with floating point numbers and hence more suitable if you want to retain the values after decimals. Use parseInt if and only if you are sure that you want the integer value.

Comment: The question was "How do I convert a String into an integer in javascript"

Answer (score 13):

We can use `+(stringOfNumber)` instead of using `parseInt(stringOfNumber)`.

Example: `+("21")` returns int of 21, like the `parseInt("21")`.

We can use this unary "+" operator for parsing float too...

Comment: But you cannot use it in formulas!  I.e. (1+("21"))*10 === 1210 !

Comment: @AlexanderVasilyev I think you can, wouldn't you just use an extra parenthesis around the `+`?

Comment: @NiCkNewman I get +("21") from the example in the answer we comment.

Comment: I really dislike this solution. It's not explicit like `parseInt` is. A common implementation is `const myNumber = +myNumberAsAString` which looks like a standard `+=` or `=+` operator at first glance. Also If used incorrectly it could lead to concatenation errors. This solution is based on the fact that 0 is *assumed* as the left-hand side when no number is provided.

Comment: I agree with @StormMuller. If for some reason a coder wishes more brevity than `parseInt`, with one more character can make it a bit clearer:  `0+"..."`. That makes it easier to not misunderstand what the result will be, however it still requires some mental thought. So still "smells". Clean coding is *saying what you mean*: use `parseInt`.

Comment: The question is how to convert a string to an integer. Unary plus however is my favorite way of converting to a number because it's the most concise, and it converts everything except bigints.

Answer (score 13):

There are many ways in JavaScript to convert a string to a number value... All are simple and handy. Choose the way which one works for you:

```
var num = Number("999.5"); //999.5
var num = parseInt("999.5", 10); //999
var num = parseFloat("999.5"); //999.5
var num = +"999.5"; //999.5
```

Also, any **Math** operation converts them to number, for example...

```
var num = "999.5" / 1; //999.5
var num = "999.5" * 1; //999.5
var num = "999.5" - 1 + 1; //999.5
var num = "999.5" - 0; //999.5
var num = Math.floor("999.5"); //999
var num = ~~"999.5"; //999
```

My prefer way is using `+` sign, which is the elegant way to convert a string to number in JavaScript.

Answer (score 12):

Also as a side note: [MooTools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MooTools) has the function toInt() which is used on any native string (or float (or integer)).

```
"2".toInt()   // 2
"2px".toInt() // 2
2.toInt()     // 2
```

Comment: The third example causes a `SyntaxError`, you should use a double dot, e.g.: `2..toInt();` the first dot will end the representation of a `Number` literal and the second dot is the property accessor.

Comment: this question isn't about mootools it's about JavaScript.

Answer (score 10):

Try `str - 0` to convert `string` to `number`.

```
> str = '0'
> str - 0
  0
> str = '123'
> str - 0
  123
> str = '-12'
> str - 0
  -12
> str = 'asdf'
> str - 0
  NaN
> str = '12.34'
> str - 0
  12.34
```

Here are two links to compare the performance of several ways to convert string to int

https://jsperf.com/number-vs-parseint-vs-plus

http://phrogz.net/js/string_to_number.html

Comment: @AlexanderYau, per this [doc](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-subtraction-operator-minus), the `'1'` will be converted to `1` by `ToNumber`, then `1 - 0` would be `1`

Comment: What do the ">" prompts imply? What environment?

Comment: @PeterMortensen, the `>` prompots is from the console of Chrome.

Answer (score 10):

In my opinion, no answer covers all edge cases as parsing a float should result in an error.

```js
function parseInteger(value) {
    if(value === '') return NaN;
    const number = Number(value);
    return Number.isInteger(number) ? number : NaN;
}
```

```js
parseInteger("4")            // 4
parseInteger("5aaa")         // NaN
parseInteger("4.33333")      // NaN
parseInteger("aaa");         // NaN
```

Comment: Returning Not A Number is a bit aggressive for a float, don't you think?

Comment: It's `parseInteger`, not `parseNumber`. I guess every solutions is a workaround since JS does not support integers and floats as separate types. We could return `null` instead of `NaN`, if Not A Number is misleading.

Answer (score 10):

**Here is the easiest solution**

```
let myNumber = "123" | 0;
```

**More easy solution**

```
let myNumber = +"123";
```

Answer (score 10):

#### String to Number in JavaScript:

##### Unary + (most recommended)

- `+numStr` is easy to use and has better performance compared with others
- Supports both integers and decimals

```js
console.log(+'123.45') // => 123.45
```

##### Some other options:

#### Parsing Strings:

- `parseInt(numStr)` for integers
- `parseFloat(numStr)` for both integers and decimals

```js
console.log(parseInt('123.456')) // => 123
console.log(parseFloat('123'))   // => 123
```

#### JavaScript Functions

- Math functions like `round(numStr), floor(numStr), ceil(numStr)` for integers
- `Number(numStr)` for both integers and decimals

```js
console.log(Math.floor('123'))     // => 123
console.log(Math.round('123.456')) // => 123
console.log(Math.ceil('123.454'))  // => 124
console.log(Number('123.123'))     // => 123.123
```

#### Unary Operators

- All basic unary operators, `+numStr`, `numStr-0`, `1*numStr`, `numStr*1`, and `numStr/1`
- All support both integers and decimals
- Be cautious about `numStr+0`. It returns a string.

```js
console.log(+'123')  // => 123
console.log('002'-0) // => 2
console.log(1*'5')   // => 5
console.log('7.7'*1) // => 7.7
console.log(3.3/1)   // =>3.3
console.log('123.123'+0, typeof ('123.123' + 0)) // => 123.1230 string
```

#### Bitwise Operators

- Two tilde `~~numStr` or left shift 0, `numStr<<0`
- Supports only integers, but not decimals

```js
console.log(~~'123')      // => 123
console.log('0123'<<0)    // => 123
console.log(~~'123.123')  // => 123
console.log('123.123'<<0) // => 123
```

```js
// Parsing
console.log(parseInt('123.456')) // => 123
console.log(parseFloat('123'))   // => 123

// Function
console.log(Math.floor('123'))     // => 123
console.log(Math.round('123.456')) // => 123
console.log(Math.ceil('123.454'))  // => 124
console.log(Number('123.123'))     // => 123.123

// Unary
console.log(+'123')  // => 123
console.log('002'-0) // => 2
console.log(1*'5')   // => 5
console.log('7.7'*1) // => 7.7
console.log(3.3/1)   // => 3.3
console.log('123.123'+0, typeof ('123.123'+0)) // => 123.1230 string

// Bitwise
console.log(~~'123')      // => 123
console.log('0123'<<0)    // => 123
console.log(~~'123.123')  // => 123
console.log('123.123'<<0) // => 123
```

Comment: This is more or less a repeat of previous answers.

Comment: Basically consolidation of all posible options that I know which also syncs with previous answers.

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way would be to use `+` like this

```
const strTen = "10"
const numTen = +strTen      // string to number conversion
console.log(typeof strTen)  // string
console.log(typeof numTen)  // number
```

Comment: That is very likely already covered in previous answers.

Answer (score 7):

I actually needed to "save" a string as an integer, for a binding between C and JavaScript, so I convert the string into an integer value:

```
/*
    Examples:
        int2str( str2int("test") ) == "test" // true
        int2str( str2int("t€st") ) // "t¬st", because "€".charCodeAt(0) is 8364, will be AND'ed with 0xff
    Limitations:
        maximum 4 characters, so it fits into an integer
*/
function str2int(the_str) {
    var ret = 0;
    var len = the_str.length;
    if (len >= 1) ret += (the_str.charCodeAt(0) & 0xff) <<  0;
    if (len >= 2) ret += (the_str.charCodeAt(1) & 0xff) <<  8;
    if (len >= 3) ret += (the_str.charCodeAt(2) & 0xff) << 16;
    if (len >= 4) ret += (the_str.charCodeAt(3) & 0xff) << 24;
    return ret;
}

function int2str(the_int) {
    var tmp = [
        (the_int & 0x000000ff) >>  0,
        (the_int & 0x0000ff00) >>  8,
        (the_int & 0x00ff0000) >> 16,
        (the_int & 0xff000000) >> 24
    ];
    var ret = "";
    for (var i=0; i<4; i++) {
        if (tmp[i] == 0)
            break;
        ret += String.fromCharCode(tmp[i]);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: That's an interesting way to store and retrieve 4-byte values. It doesn't answer the conventional interpretation of the question: how to convert a string representation of a number into an integer value. Regardless, your `int2str` function stops if a byte is 0, which could be a legitimate element within the value, so the `if`...`break` should be removed so you get a complete 4-byte value returned.

Answer (score 5):

```
function parseIntSmarter(str) {
    // ParseInt is bad because it returns 22 for "22thisendsintext"
    // Number() is returns NaN if it ends in non-numbers, but it returns 0 for empty or whitespace strings.
    return isNaN(Number(str)) ? NaN : parseInt(str, 10);
}
```

Comment: However, be aware that `Number` supports some special formats, that `parseInt` will incorrectly interpret.  For example, `Number("0x11")` => `17`, then `parseInt` will return `0`. It might be better to **search for non-digits**, if goal is to reject all non-Integers. **Or** could do `var f = Number(str); return f.isInteger() ? f : NaN;` Depending on exactly what you want to allow/reject.

Answer (score 4):

The safest way to ensure you get a valid integer:

```
let integer = (parseInt(value, 10) || 0);
```

Examples:

```
// Example 1 - Invalid value:
let value = null;
let integer = (parseInt(value, 10) || 0);
// => integer = 0
```

```
// Example 2 - Valid value:
let value = "1230.42";
let integer = (parseInt(value, 10) || 0);
// => integer = 1230
```

```
// Example 3 - Invalid value:
let value = () => { return 412 };
let integer = (parseInt(value, 10) || 0);
// => integer = 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Summing the multiplication of digits with their respective power of ten:

i.e: 123 = 100+20+3 = 1*100 + 2+10 + 3*1 = 1*(10^2) + 2*(10^1) + 3*(10^0)

```
function atoi(array) {

    // Use exp as (length - i), other option would be
    // to reverse the array.
    // Multiply a[i] * 10^(exp) and sum

    let sum = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        let exp = array.length - (i+1);
        let value = array[i] * Math.pow(10, exp);
        sum += value;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use plus.
For example:

```
var personAge = '24';
var personAge1 = (+personAge)
```

then you can see the new variable's type by`typeof personAge1` ; which is `number`.

Comment: Could you please explain what + is in this case and how the casting happens?

Answer (score 3):

#### Number()

```
Number(" 200.12 ")  // Returns 200.12

Number("200.12")  // Returns 200.12

Number("200") // Returns 200
```

#### parseInt()

```
parseInt(" 200.12 ")  // Return 200

parseInt("200.12")  // Return 200

parseInt("200") // Return 200

parseInt("Text information") // Returns NaN
```

#### parseFloat()

It will return the first number

```
parseFloat("200 400")  // Returns 200

parseFloat("200") // Returns 200

parseFloat("Text information") // Returns NaN

parseFloat("200.10")  // Return 200.10
```

#### Math.floor()

Round a number to the nearest integer

```
Math.floor(" 200.12 ")  // Return 200

Math.floor("200.12")  // Return 200

Math.floor("200") // Return 200
```

Answer (score 1):

As of ES2015 you can use `Math.trunc()` to convert strings to integer:

```
Math.trunc("33.33") // returns 33
Math.trunc("-5999999999.99999") // returns -5999999999
```

Or, if you need to support old browsers or you just prefer to avoid using a function, you can use the [remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) trick to get the remainder when dividing by 1, then subtract. Unlike the answers that use bitwise operators, this successfully handles large numbers (with the exception of Infinity which becomes NaN.)

```
var a = "-5999999999.99999"
a-=a%1// converts a to -5999999999
```

Finally, if you need to handle Infinity, there is this split trick that works with non-negative numbers by splitting on a decimal point thereby removing the decimal portion of the string followed by converting to a number with [unary +](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus). This also works when converting strings without decimals:

```
var a = "5999999999.99999"
a = +a.split(".")[0];// converts a to 5999999999
```

Note that all of the above solutions will convert an empty string to 0. If that's not what you want then you need to check for that condition first.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to double XOR the value with itself:

```javascript
var i = 12.34;
console.log('i = ' + i);
console.log('i ⊕ i ⊕ i = ' + (i ^ i ^ i));
```

This will output:

```javascript
i = 12.34
i ⊕ i ⊕ i = 12
```

Comment: Perhaps elaborate in your answer? Why does that work? (But *********** ***without*** *********** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Answer (score 0):

I only added one plus(+) before string and that was solution!

```
+"052254" // 52254
```

Comment: This is already covered in a previous answer, [Nosredna's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133770/how-to-convert-a-string-to-an-integer-in-javascript/1133814#1133814).

Answer (score -1):

All of the previous answers are correct. Please be sure before that this is a number in a string by doing "typeot x === 'number'". Otherwise, it will return NaN.

```
var num = "fsdfsdf242342";
typeof num => 'string';

var num1 = "12423";
typeof num1 => 'number';
+num1 = > 12423`
```

Comment: In node v8.5.0, `var num1 = "12423"; typeof num1;` returns `string`.

Comment: If your goal is to avoid `NaN`, then the straightforward solution is to *test the value you get back for `NaN`*: `var v = whatever-conversion-you-prefer(s); if (isNaN(v)) ...handle the error... else ...use v...`.

Answer (score -1):

```js
function doSth(){
  var a = document.getElementById('input').value;
  document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = toNumber(a) + 1;
}
function toNumber(str){
  return +str;
}
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text">
<input onclick="doSth()" type="submit">
<span id="number"></span>
```

Answer (score -1):

This (probably) isn't the best solution for *parsing* an integer, but if you need to "extract" one, for example:

```js
"1a2b3c" === 123
"198some text2hello world!30" === 198230
// ...
```

this would work (only for integers):

```js
var str = '3a9b0c3d2e9f8g'

function extractInteger(str) {
  var result = 0;
  var factor = 1

  for (var i = str.length; i > 0; i--) {
    if (!isNaN(str[i - 1])) {
      result += parseInt(str[i - 1]) * factor
      factor *= 10
    }
  }

  return result
}

console.log(extractInteger(str))
```

Of course, this would also work for parsing an integer, but would be slower than other methods.

You could also parse integers with this method and return `NaN` if the string isn't a number, but I don't see why you'd want to since this relies on `parseInt` internally and `parseInt` is probably faster.

```js
var str = '3a9b0c3d2e9f8g'

function extractInteger(str) {
  var result = 0;
  var factor = 1

  for (var i = str.length; i > 0; i--) {
    if (isNaN(str[i - 1])) return NaN
    result += parseInt(str[i - 1]) * factor
    factor *= 10
  }

  return result
}

console.log(extractInteger(str))
```

Answer (score -2):

I use this

```
String.prototype.toInt = function (returnval) {
    var i = parseInt(this);
     return isNaN(i) ? returnval !== undefined ? returnval : - 1  :      i;
}

var str = "7";
var num = str.toInt(); // outputs 7, if not str outputs -1
//or
var num = str.toInt(0); // outputs 7, if not str outputs 0
```

This way I always get an int back.

Comment: Why does it need to be so complex?